# default page issue with 4.0 ASP.NET and MVC mixed mode website

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am converting a classic ASP.NET 4.0 site to also use MVC.  Over time I am migrating the ASP.NET code to MVC, but during the transition both technologies will be in use.

If I navigate to the default page (ie, http://mywebsite.com/), then MVC routing is taking over and returning the following message.

> This request has been blocked because sensitive information could be
>   disclosed to third party web sites when this is used in a GET request.
>   To allow GET requests, set JsonRequestBehavior to AllowGet

If I use http://mywebsite.com/default.aspx, then everything works fine.

My route config looks like...

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        //ignore aspx pages (web forms take care of these)
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.aspx/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Notice I am ignoring .aspx page requests, so these requests get ignored by the MVC pipeline.  However, I need 'no page specified' default requests to process `default.aspx`.  How would I change the above code or configure the site/IIS to make this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the default route and now the behavior is as needed.

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        //ignore aspx pages (web forms take care of these)
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.aspx/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Comment: but this way your MVC routing will not work perfectly, like you need to type http://localhost:16671/admin/index instead of http://localhost:16671/admin, it will not take index of a view folder by default